# How to send UDP message in ballerina?

Tags: wso2, ballerina

I would like to know whether it is possible to send and receive UDP message in ballerina. Basically in java I can do the following using the Datagram Socket.

```
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(
                    payload.getBytes(),
                    payload.length(),
                    InetAddress.getByName(address),
                    port
            );
            socket.send(packet);
```

I want to replicate the same functionality in ballerina to implement a peer to peer network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending UDP messages is not supported yet. There is a ballerina socket standard library which supports TCP level listener and client which can be used to send/receive TCP messages as below. There are plans to add UDP support also with this socket library in future.

```
import ballerina/io;
import ballerina/socket;

public function main() {
    socket:Client socketClient = new({ host: "localhost", port: 61598,
        callbackService: ClientService });
    string content = "Hello Ballerina";
    byte[] payloadByte = content.toByteArray("UTF-8");

    var writeResult = socketClient->write(payloadByte);
    if (writeResult is error) {
        io:println("Unable to written the content ", writeResult);
    }
}
```

Refer - https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/tcp-socket-listener-client.html